# Deleting s3 file also deletes the folder python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to delete all the files inside a folder in S3 Bucket using the below python code but the folder is also getting deleted along with the file

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
old_bucket_name='new-bucket'
old_prefix='data/'
old_bucket = s3.Bucket(old_bucket_name)

old_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=old_prefix).delete()
```

Comment: Actually there are no "folders" in S3, it is only a way how objects are displayed in the console based on their key (name) prefix. If you create a folder in a console, it will create an empty file with the prefix (path) name. Your code deletes all objects with their key (full path) begining with the prefix, so there is nothing left to denote the folder

Comment: How can I delete the file without deleting the folder I have created?

Comment: Maybe you could apply another filter to delete only objects where the key length is longer than the prefix length (I'm not a python guy, not sure how to do it exactly).  Regardless that the folder is only a prefix or an empty file (with special content type), so maybe you do't really needed that

Comment: Do you particularly _need_ the folder to exist?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  I need folders for organizing different files in different folders instead of creating many buckets.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. You can create files where ever you wish, but please note that you do not actually need to create the folders. If you store an object with a name of `data/foo.txt`, then the `data` directory automatically comes into existence. You could even create an object called `australia/nsw/sydney/foo.txt` and it would work. The three folders would be automatically created for you (but they don't actually exist). The easiest thing is just to pretend that they already exist and everything works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

S3 does not have folders. Object names can contain `/` and the console will represent objects with common prefixes that contain a `/` as folders, but the folder does not actually exist. If you're looking to have that visual representation, you can create a zero-length object that ends with a `/` which is basically equivalent to what the console does if you create a folder via the UI.

Relevant docs can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html)

Comment: @Nishanth Actually - in the console if a user creates a folder, the console creates an empty file with content type `application/x-directory` and key with a folder name (e.g. `data/`) just to shiw an empty folder. But without an additional filter the shared code will delete even the special file. Still I believe you may reconsider if you really need "folders"

Comment: @gusto2 I understand the complexity with folders.I have decided to take an alternate approach instead(creating more buckets instead of folders)